# embedding a php webpage inside a webpage like vanilla forums embed plugin

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I am creating this website (php app). Let's call it Site1 (so ingenious, I know).

I want other people to be able to "embed" my site into their site/their webpages. Something similar to [Vanilla embed plugin](http://vanillaforums.org/vforg/features/embed-vanilla)
For example, if you wanted to embed Vanilla forum into your webpage, all you need to do is: copy and paste this forum embed code into the remote application where you would like the forum to appear.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://embed.vanillaforums.com/plugins/embedvanilla/remote.js"></script>
```

If you insert that code, the forums would appear in your webpage.

I want other people to be able to embed my app into their page as well. I am not sure how to code my site in a way that it can be done.

To put things in context:
My php app is going to be a "classified-directory" app. It will list out some classifieds based on user's location. So, when user embeds my app into their page, we also need to make sure they have a way of passing "correct" location so that my app (embedded inside their webpage) shows correct classified listings.

Thanks

Comment: I bet the time you have invested to write this question would have given you the insight by looking into the source how this is done. The javascript in question is creating an iframe which displays http://embed.vanillaforums.com/.

Comment: @hakre - this is exactly what I was thinking. I should have looked at the code first. So, I'll create two versions of my site:
Say embed.site1.com and www.site1.com
For people who want to embed my site, they'd embed embed.site1.com inside their iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual build of your remote site has little in this case to do with embedding on another's website. The real key to your solution is inside of `http://embed.vanillaforums.com/plugins/embedvanilla/remote.js`. I'm not going to tell you how to go about it (leave that bit up to you), but the above script essentially creates and formats an iFrame on the user's page containing the remote application. Study the script and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @65Fbef05. Well, my webpage is going to have a header, footer etc. So, I was concerned that maybe I'd have to create a version of my app without the header/footer/logo/sidebar text. 
I thought this is what I'd have to do:
-> create a page version where the only output is classified-listing (no header, no footer etc.)
-> user can then insert this page in an iframe

Comment: The iFrame will pull all the content from your site as if it were a new browser window or tab. Treat it like any other webpage. One thing you may want to do is purchase an ssl certificate though - some people will be making requests for your page from a secured connection.

Comment: @ 65Fbef05 which means I do indeed need to create a version of my website (php app) that strips-off everything (logo, header, footer) and just displays classified listing. This can then be embedded into user's page. If I don't create such a version, my user's page would show their logo etc. and then inside the iframe, it'd show my logo etc. too. Which would look incredibly clumsy.

Comment: So you __don't__ want the header and footer showing up on another user's page - I see now. Well, 6 one way, half a dozen another. Whatever you decide to serve up is what will be delivered.

Comment: @Red Sci: You can proxy your page's output and strip everything but the content you would like to preserve, e.g. with DomDocument. Or with another line of CSS *gg*.

Comment: Thanks @ 65Fbef05.
@hakre - not sure what you mean by one line of css? Are you suggesting that I may not have to create another version of my site at all. I was thinking I'd have to do something like this: Regular version: Site1.com/index.php but for iframe version, I'd have to create iframe optimized version: site1.com/**index_iframe.php**   and then user can emebed **index_iframe.php** inside their iframe

Comment: @Red Sci: Sure you can do that, sounds valid. there are multiple ways. with a line of CSS I meant, that for the iframe version you can just provide some CSS that is hiding the header and the footer of your standard page for a quick mockup.